# My plots are overlapping while using Show[] command

Tags: plotting

I want to display these two equations in one graph. Both are having different values but by using `Show` command only single line comes in graph.
My Code is:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[
  Table[(1/x)^3/(Sqrt[π]) N[
     MeijerG[{{-5/2, -2}, {}}, {{2, -2}, {-3}}, 1/x]], {x, 10}]], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[172 (1/y)^(9/2)/(5760000000 Sqrt[π]) N[
     MeijerG[{{-5/2, -2}, {}}, {{2, -2}, {-3}}, 1/y]], {y, 10}]], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: First of all, `Sqrt[[Pi]]` (occurs twice) means to take `Pi`-th part of `Sqrt`, which is nonsense. Perhaps you mean `Sqrt[Pi]`?

Comment: Both graphs are there. It is just that your second graph has very small values that it appears horizontal. Try adding `PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}` option in your second `ListLinePlot`, and you'll see what is happening.

Comment: You can add the option `AxesOrigin -> {0, -0.2}` to the first `ListLinePlot` or `Frame -> True` to `Show` to increase the visibility of the second plot.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

### Example

```
Show[{
  ListLinePlot[Table[(1/x)^3/(Sqrt[\[Pi]]) N[MeijerG[{{-5/2, -2}, {}}, {{2, -2}, {-3}}, 1/x]], {x, 10}]], 
  ListLinePlot[Table[172 (1/y)^(9/2)/(5760000000 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) N[MeijerG[{{-5/2, -2}, {}}, {{2, -2}, {-3}}, 1/y]], {y, 10}]]
  },
 Frame -> True
]
```

### Output

### [image: output]